# Oracle using REGEXP_SUBSTR to return values within brackets

Tags: regex, oracle

We store some application parameters in our database and I am looking for a method via SQL to extract/parse the parameters out.  An example of this data would be the following:

```
PROJS["AA",ZZZZ[PARAMETER["One",1]],PROJECTION["Transverse"],UNIT["Two",2]]
```

So for example the value for Projection would be "Transverse" and quotes would be part of that.  I figured the easiest approach to getting this out would be using the REGEXP_SUBSTR function.  This is my current attempt:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('PROJS["AA",ZZZZ[PARAMETER["One",1]],PROJECTION["Transverse"],UNIT["Two",2]]', 'PROJECTION\[[^][]*\]') FROM dual;
```

That though returns:

```
PROJECTION["Transverse"]
```

I realize that I could then just strip out the unneeded characters but I was curious if someone could recommend any REGEX tweaks so that the SELECT query instead returns simply "Transverse" for this example.  Projection is not always what I'd want to pull out though, for example if I wanted Unit then I'd need returned: "Two",2

This is using Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
   'PROJS["AA",ZZZZ[PARAMETER["One",1]],PROJECTION["Transverse"],UNIT["Two",2]]',
   '^.*PROJECTION\[(.+?)\].*$', '\1'
) FROM dual
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use backreferences (`\1`, `\2`, etc.) for this. Basically you want to match three parts of the string:

1. Everything before the `PROJECTION` parameter value.
2. The `PROJECTION` parameter value.
3. Everything after the `PROJECTION` parameter value.

These three matching regexes have to be inside of parentheses for the backreferencing to work. The regex I came up with is this:

```
(.*PROJECTION\[")(.+)("].*)
                     ^^^^^^ Backref 3: everything after the PROJECTION parameter value
                 ^^^^ Backref 2: the PROJECTION parameter value
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Backref 1: everything before the PROJECTION parameter value
```

Then just replace with backref 2, ignoring 1 and 3:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(expr, '(.*PROJECTION\[")(.+)("].*)', '\2')
```

Comment: When I try that I get an ORA-01722.  This is what I tried to test:  SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('PROJS["AA",ZZZZ[PARAMETER["One",1]],PROJECTION["Transverse"],PARAMETER["Two",2]]', '(.*PROJECTION\[")(.+)("].*)', '\2') FROM dual;

Comment: The regex is for `REGEXP_REPLACE`, not `REGEXP_SUBSTR`. The `ORA-01722` is because `REGEXP_SUBSTR` expects a numeric for its third argument so it's choking on the `'\2'`.

Comment: That said, I'd still go with the answer from Egor, which is more compact, and slicker with the user of the non-greedy matching. I'll leave this answer here though because (a) I'm pretty sure it works and (b) it explains the backreferences. It may not be best for your needs but someone who stumbles across this post may find it useful.

Comment: Sorry about that, I should drink my coffee before reading replies online.  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('PROJS["AA",ZZZZ[PARAMETER["One",1]],PROJECTION["Transverse"],UNIT["Two",2]]', 'PROJECTION\[([^][]*)\]', 1, 1, null, 1) FROM dual;
```

Comment: You should add some explanations to improve the quality of your answer.